# How to rename a resource in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, resources

Okay, I've never done win32 programming before, and I have a question that seems fairly stupid..

[image]

How do I rename `IDR_MENU1` to, for example, `IDR_MAIN_MENU`? I tried everything couldn't find a way.

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795770/10147399) answer instead as it's more up to date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the resource if you select your resource, example IDR_MENU1 in resource view. Activate the property palette (Ctrl +W, P) and you can then edit the IDR_MENU1 value.

Comment: The shortcut CTRL+W,P doesn't work in VC 2008. Using Alt+Enter, it works.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Dave D.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795770/10147399) is better.

Answer (score 15):

This is from 2011, but I didn't see a good answer.

Here is one easy way to rename IDR_MENU1 to another name. Select IDR_MENU1, then hit ALT + ENTER. This will show the 'Properties' window. Here you can rename IDR_MENU1 under 'Id'.

Comment: As noted below, the accepted answer is out-of-date.  This answer works in VS2019.

Answer (score 2):

Exit Visual Studio and then edit the `DbcEditor.RC` file.
And replace all occurrences of `IDR_MENU1` with whatever you want.

Comment: I am not aware of any. One thing I would advise is that once you change your RC file outside editor, you need to take care of any code which has reference to the old resource name (i.e. `IDR_MENU1`).